# How do I add columns to data from a Flat File Source in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a Flat File Source that reads data from a file with two "columns" of data. One is an ID and the other is a date. I want to read this data from the file and "dress" it with two more columns before I write it to the database. I want to add one column with the value of getdate() and one column with just a 1 in it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this an MS SQL question? If so, please add "in MS SQL" to the end of the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a derived column transformation to add two new columns. Select the add as new column from the the derived column property and name your derived column names accordingly. Populate the expression property with the date time function : GETDATE() and populate the other column with a 1. Hope this helps.